# Enable Shopping Cart/Woocommerce on one region of WPML

Tags: wordpress

I have multiple regional multi-lingual website set up on wordpress. It loads UK region set up on

`www.domain.com/?lang=gb`

and US region loads up on

`www.domain.com/?lang=en`

Now i want to add shopping cart to UK region of the site. Is it possible at all?

Like when users open up `www.domain.com/?lang=gb`, I show shopping cart and products there. Where as when user load `www.domain.com/?lang=en`, it shows simple site with no shopping cart or products.

Any help/guide here will be helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this to remove add to cart system if the user is not from GB.

```
if(!ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'gb'){ // ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE is WPML constant to check current page language
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart');
}
```

But if you want to remove products from catalog list?Then what do you mean by simple site with no shopping cart or products. And What do you want to show on this page instead ( Blog Posts?? ) ?